# Checking the first element of json

Tags: json, laravel

I am very new to Json and need to access elements of json:

```
$users=User::all()->toJson();
```

`print_r($users[0])` gives only `[`

and `print_r($users[0]->email)` gives me the error trying to get property of non object.

`$users[0]["email"]` gives Illegal string offset 'email'.

`$users[0].email` Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'email'

How do i get the name of first user?

Comment: Could you also post your json?

Answer (score 0):

it acts like a string so it shows only `[` while `$user[0]`.. don't use `toJson()`

```
$users = User::all();
$email = $users[0]->email;
```

is enough. to get the value from the array.